# How can I asynchronously receive processed messages in Celery?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, rabbitmq, celery

I'm writing a data processing pipeline using Celery because this speeds things up considerably.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
    from celery.result import ResultSet
    from some_celery_app import processing_task # of type @app.task

    def crunch_data():
        results = ResultSet([])
        for document in mongo.find(): #Around 100K - 1M documents
            job = processing_task.delay(document)
            results.add(job)

        return results.get()

    collected_data = crunch_data()
    #Do some stuff with this collected data
```

I successfully spawn four workers with concurrency enabled and when I run this script, the data is processed accordingly and I can do whatever I want.

I'm using RabbitMQ as message broker and `rpc` as backend.

What I see when I open the RabbitMQ management UI:

1. First, all the documents are processed
2. then, and only then, are the documents retrieved by the collective `results.get()` call.

My question: Is there a way to do the processing and subsequent retrieval simultaneously? In my case, as all documents are atomic entities that do not rely on each other, there seems to be no need to wait for the job to be processed completely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the callback parameter in `ResultSet.get(callback=cbResult)` and then you could process the result in the callback.

```
def cbResult(task_id, value):
  print(value)
results.get(callback=cbResult)
```